# which function that linux kernel use to kick start the scheduler

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

Hi I am studying the Linux kernel source code, and am trying to understand how Linux kernel scheduler works, the question I have is:
Is there a function in linux kernel for the kernel to kick start the scheduler and is there a flow chart with all the kernel function sys call that I can refer to about the scheduling part? I can find the TCP/IP stack flow chart quite easily but not the scheduling part. 
Any help is greatly appreciated !

Comment: Are you talking about crontab?

Comment: I think your question is too broad for stackoverflow rules, but maybe you can find useful informations here : https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/Initialization/linux-initialization-8.html and here : https://trepo.tuni.fi/bitstream/handle/10024/96864/GRADU-1428493916.pdf